# Official XSD schema not valid

Tags: xml, xsd

Here is my XSD file: http://www.da-ra.de/fileadmin/media/da-ra.de/Technik/4.0/dara.xsd.
I got it from https://www.da-ra.de/dara/typo3/typo3?lang=en&ext=en%2Ftechnical-information%2Fdoi-registration%2F.

When I put the XSD file into the XSD validator (http://www.utilities-online.info/xsdvalidation/#.XOKFnKTgphE) and check XSD validity, it says that it's not valid. Does anyone know why is that? The XSD file should bi fine, given the fact that it is from official site.

The error from validator:

```
Not valid.
Warning - Line 7, 69: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 7; columnNumber: 69; schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'include/dara-resourceType-v4.1.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
Warning - Line 12, 69: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 12; columnNumber: 69; schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'include/dara-otherTitleType-v4.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
Warning - Line 17, 70: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 17; columnNumber: 70; schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'include/dara-contributorType-v4.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
Warning - Line 22, 71: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 22; columnNumber: 71; schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'include/dara-availabilityType-v4.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
Warning - Line 27, 69: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 27; columnNumber: 69; schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'include/dara-relationType-v4.1.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
Warning - Line 32, 62: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 32; columnNumber: 62; schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'include/dara-pidType-v4.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
Warning - Line 37, 70: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 37; columnNumber: 70; schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'include/dara-descriptionType-v4.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
Warning - Line 42, 75: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 42; columnNumber: 75; schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'include/dara-identifierSchemaType-v4.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
Warning - Line 47, 72: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 47; columnNumber: 72; schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'include/dara-timeDimensionType-v4.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
Warning - Line 52, 73: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 52; columnNumber: 73; schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'include/dara-collectionModeType-v4.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
Warning - Line 57, 67: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 57; columnNumber: 67; schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'include/dara-documentType-v4.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
Warning - Line 62, 63: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 62; columnNumber: 63; schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'include/dara-unitType-v4.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
Warning - Line 67, 67: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 67; columnNumber: 67; schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'include/dara-rightsCCType-v4.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
Warning - Line 72, 68: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 72; columnNumber: 68; schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'include/dara-languageCodes-v4.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
Warning - Line 77, 76: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 77; columnNumber: 76; schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'include/dara-resourceLanguageCodes-v4.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
Warning - Line 82, 87: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 82; columnNumber: 87; schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'include/dara-internalClassificationSchemaType-v4.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
Warning - Line 87, 82: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 87; columnNumber: 82; schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'include/dara-controlledKeywordSchemaType-v4.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
Warning - Line 92, 63: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 92; columnNumber: 63; schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'include/dara-geoCodes-v4.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
Error - Line 99, 57: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 99; columnNumber: 57; src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'resourceType' to a(n) 'type definition' component.
Error - Line 482, 65: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 482; columnNumber: 65; src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'resourceLanguage' to a(n) 'type definition' component.
Error - Line 489, 57: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 489; columnNumber: 57; src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'metadataLanguage' to a(n) 'type definition' component.
Error - Line 1582, 69: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1582; columnNumber: 69; src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'collectionModeType' to a(n) 'type definition' component.
Error - Line 1877, 65: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1877; columnNumber: 65; src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'availabilityType' to a(n) 'type definition' component.
Error - Line 2267, 47: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 2267; columnNumber: 47; src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'pidType' to a(n) 'type definition' component.
Error - Line 207, 63: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 207; columnNumber: 63; src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'titleType' to a(n) 'type definition' component.
Error - Line 565, 105: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 565; columnNumber: 105; src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'classificationSchemaType' to a(n) 'type definition' component.
Error - Line 659, 79: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 659; columnNumber: 79; src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'keywordSchemaType' to a(n) 'type definition' component.
Error - Line 779, 75: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 779; columnNumber: 75; src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'descriptionType' to a(n) 'type definition' component.
Error - Line 808, 119: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 808; columnNumber: 119; src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'geographicCoverageControlled' to a(n) 'type definition' component.
Error - Line 1222, 83: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1222; columnNumber: 83; src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'timeDimensionType' to a(n) 'type definition' component.
Error - Line 1308, 87: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1308; columnNumber: 87; src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'contributorType' to a(n) 'type definition' component.
Error - Line 1352, 87: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1352; columnNumber: 87; src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'contributorType' to a(n) 'type definition' component.
Error - Line 2409, 57: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 2409; columnNumber: 57; src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'unitType' to a(n) 'type definition' component.
Error - Line 1910, 71: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1910; columnNumber: 71; src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'licenseType' to a(n) 'type definition' component.
Error - Line 1963, 66: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1963; columnNumber: 66; src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'pidType' to a(n) 'type definition' component.
Error - Line 1968, 69: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1968; columnNumber: 69; src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'relationType' to a(n) 'type definition' component.
Error - Line 1973, 83: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1973; columnNumber: 83; src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'resourceType' to a(n) 'type definition' component.
Error - Line 2051, 83: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 2051; columnNumber: 83; src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'documentType' to a(n) 'type definition' component.
Error - Line 2398, 81: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 2398; columnNumber: 81; src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'identifierSchemaType' to a(n) 'type definition' component.
```

Comment: Looks like the file depends on importing other XSD files which are not present - probably because you didn't download them or the folder structure is incorrect.

Comment: Thanks. Solved my problem by importing other dependent XSD files.